# Obtener una matriz PHP con los meses como índice

Tags: php

Necesito traerme todos los datos de la base de datos agrupados por meses.

Lo estoy haciendo de esta forma:

```
$inversionLineal = Contract::where('type_interes', 'lineal')->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')])->select(DB::raw('count(*) as contratos'),DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as mes"))->groupBy('mes')->get()->toArray();
```

Y me devuelve un array como este:

```
[
{
"contratos": 1,
"mes": "06"
},

{
"contratos": 1,
"mes": "08"
},

{
"contratos": 1,
"mes": "09"
},

{
"contratos": 1,
"mes": "10"
}
]
```

Pero lo que necesito es que, por ejemplo, me genere una matriz de 12 índices (meses) de la siguiente forma:

```
[0,0,5,10,15,20,23,24,32,40,20,40]
```

Es decir, que de una vez me traiga el número de contratos que hubo cada mes.

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo en la consulta SQL o mediante código PHP?

Comment: Mediante código php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener lo que deseas desde PHP puedes hacer un bucle que asigne los valores adecuados de cada posición de la matriz.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* Inicialmente todos los meses tienen un valor de 0 */
$meses = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
/* Realizamos la consulta */
$inversionLineal = Contract::where('type_interes', 'lineal')
  ->whereBetween(
    'created_at',
    [
      $from,
      \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')
    ]
  )
  ->select(
    DB::raw('count(*) as contratos'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as mes")
  )
  ->groupBy('mes')
  ->get()
  ->toArray();
/* Iteramos cada registro del resultado */
foreach($inversionLineal as $registro) {
  /* Rellenamos el mes adecuado de la matriz */
  $meses[intval($registro->mes) - 1] = $registro->contratos;
}
```

En `$meses` tendrás los datos de cada mes.

Hay que tener en cuenta que en las matrices los índices empiezan por `0`, mientras que los meses empiezan por el `1`. Por ese motivo resto uno al mes obtenido de la base de datos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era exactamente lo que estaba buscando